# Implement polymorphic relationship with an indirect type/id column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, orm, rails-activerecord

I have the following database schema:

```sql
CREATE TABLE public.my_model_foo (
    id bigint NOT NULL,
    foo character varying,
    created_at timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
    updated_at timestamp without time zone NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE public.my_model_bar (
    id bigint NOT NULL,
    bar character varying,
    created_at timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
    updated_at timestamp without time zone NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE public.my_model_indirect (
    id bigint NOT NULL,
    type character varying NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE ONLY public.my_model_foo
    ADD CONSTRAINT my_model_foo_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id);

ALTER TABLE ONLY public.my_model_bar
    ADD CONSTRAINT my_model_bar_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id);

ALTER TABLE ONLY public.my_model_indirect
    ADD CONSTRAINT my_model_indirect_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id);

ALTER TABLE ONLY public.my_model_foo
    ADD CONSTRAINT fk_rails_a07be81d64 FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES public.my_model_indirect(id);

ALTER TABLE ONLY public.my_model_bar
    ADD CONSTRAINT fk_rails_157422fcc5 FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES public.my_model_indirect(id);
```

So basically the `my_model_foo` and `my_model_bar` tables contain the columns for the `MyModel::Foo` and `MyModel::Bar` ActiveRecord models, but they take their ID from the shared table `my_model_indirect`. The `type` column on there would be set the same way Rails expects it to be set up for a polymorphic relationship, i.e. populated with the appropriate model name.

My question is, now, given this database schema, how would I go about creating a polymorphic `belongs_to` relationship to either a `MyModel::Foo` or a `MyModel::Bar` through the `type` column in the `my_model_indirect` table? I know I could just use `polymorphic: true` if the id/type columns were directly embedded into the model I was setting the relationship on, but then I would lose the foreign key advantages, and I'm not sure how to set the ORM up to handle this approach?

What I would like to happen is to be able to add a `model_id` reference that would be a foreign key to `my_model_indirect.id`, and when the model is loaded, Rails would fetch the `type` from `my_model_indirect` based on the `model_id`, and then retrieve the associated object from the corresponding table.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean "they take their ID from the shared table my_model_indirect"? They both have their own PRIMARY KEY as shown. It is very unclear what you hope to accomplish here since the addition of another column in the `my_model_indirect` table would make this a true polymorph

Comment: @engineersmnky notice the foreign key constraints on the primary key ids of both my_model_foo and my_model_bar

Answer (score 1):

Rails thinks polymorphic relationships are resolved by two fields, an id and a type. When you use `polymorphic: true` in a migration it creates two fields, the type saved as a string which references the class name and the id associated with that reference.

We solve the "belongs_to" problem in the class level with

`belongs_to :fooable, polymorphic: true`

You could generate a union to specify the possible types to fulfill the polymorphic slot, but it may not actually be necessary.

for a migration

`add_reference :my_tables, :fooable, polymorphic: true`

you can have the parent object `baz` do something like this:

```
class MyModel::Baz < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_one :foo, as: fooable
end
```

child objects

```
class MyModel::Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :fooable, polymorphic: true
end
```